# Frame showing up super small Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jcomponent

could someone tell me why my frame is showing up super small/minimized? I thought I just had to pack my frame to resolve the issue but packing my frame does not seem to have any effect on the outcome.

[small frame / frame not showing up properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbpjH.png)

Here's my code:

```
package welcome.netbeans;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class WelcomeNetbeans extends JFrame {
    private JLabel welcomeText;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WelcomeNetbeans frame = new WelcomeNetbeans();    
        frame.start();
    }
    
    public void start() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        Container cont = getContentPane();
        cont.add(panel);
        
        setSize(300, 300);
        setTitle("Welcome Netbeans!");
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setFocusable(true);
        
        welcomeText = new JLabel("Wecome Netbeans!");
        welcomeText.setSize(100, 50);
        panel.add(welcomeText);
        
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: `setSize(300, 300);` directly after `pack();`.

Comment: Better yet, don't set sizes, but rather fill the JFrame with needed components, call `pack()` and let the JFrame and the layout managers size themselves.

Comment: I put setSize after pack and it still did not work, and neither did removing setSize completely

Comment: You must understand that most layout managers do not respect a component's size but rather its *preferred* size. You *could* call `setPreferredSize(...)` on the JLabel but doing so would still miss the point and make for rigid GUI's that might not work well. Myself, I often set the label's Font and sometimes give it an empty border, anything to avoid setting sizes and preferred sizes directly. Occasionally, I'll override a component's `getPreferredSize() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must understand that most layout managers do not respect a component's size, but rather its *preferred* size. And so calling `setSize(...)` on a component usually won't help you.  You *could* call `setPreferredSize(...)` on the JLabel but doing so would still miss the point and make for rigid GUI's that might not work well. Myself, I often set the label's Font and sometimes give it an empty border, anything to avoid setting sizes and preferred sizes directly. Occasionally, I'll override a component's `getPreferredSize() method.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class MyWelcomeGui extends JPanel {
    private static final float LABEL_FONT_SIZE = 60.0f;
    private static final int PADDING = 60;
    private static final String TITLE = "Wecome To My GUI!";
    private static final Color BACKGROUND = new Color(51, 255, 189);

    MyWelcomeGui() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(TITLE, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, LABEL_FONT_SIZE));
        Border border = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(PADDING, PADDING, PADDING, PADDING);
        label.setBorder(border);
        label.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        setBackground(BACKGROUND);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(label);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame window = new JFrame();
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                window.add(new MyWelcomeGui());
                window.pack();
                window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                window.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Hello, removing the size of the components did not help. Even with this same exact code (just a different file name), I still received the same minimized/small tab look. I put a print statement in front of the declaration of the JFrame in run(), and it was not printed. I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work after building and cleaning my project. Thank you!